# Spark - Converting DataFrame to RowMatrix to compute all-pairs similarity efficiently

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, recommendation-engine

I have a big DataFrame filled with relations between users and items, like this:

```
        item1  item2
user1       0      1
user2       1      0
```

and want to solve the all-pairs similarity problem efficiently.

I saw I could use the `columnSimilarities` method of the `pyspark.mllib` module if I were working with a `RowMatrix` object.

As every method I've come up with to solve this with a `DataFrame` seems quite inefficient, I'd like to know the best possible way to obtain a `RowMatrix` from my `DataFrame`.

Or, in the best case, if I'm missing something and there's a better way to face the all-pairs similarity problem with a `DataFrame`, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: I can show the method to get `RowMatrix` but if you can explain the problem you want to solve with an example, I can try to solve it through `DataFrame` itself.

Comment: Hello Mayank, thank you for the answer. Would like to know your method to get `RowMatrix` even if you manage to solve my problem from a `DataFrame`. 

Anyway, what I want is to get the top-similar rows to each row in my `DataFrame`. The method implemented by Spark that I want to use but can only use with `RowMatrix` is presented here: https://databricks.com/blog/2014/10/20/efficient-similarity-algorithm-now-in-spark-twitter.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in other answers, there's no way to directly transform a `DataFrame` into a `RowMatrix`. You first need to get an `RDD` object.

To do so **on Python**:

```
your_rdd = your_dataframe.rdd.map(list)
your_rowmatrix = RowMatrix(your_rdd)
```

Comment: Is there any sample for the output shape?

Answer (score 0):

After reading a little bit about `RowMatrix`, it looks like you need to transform your `dataframe` to an `RDD`.

To do so you can use :

```
val rows = df.content.rdd.map{ case row =>
Vectors.dense(row.toSeq.toArray.map{
    x => x.asInstanceOf[Integer]
  })
}.collect
```

thene use `rows` in your code.

I hope that this is helpful.

Comment: This is sound Scala